# how can I load images in base64 string by url-loader in typescript + react (rails5 + webpacker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpacker

### example repo https://github.com/github0013/typescript_react

I need to load images in base64 string **embeded into  tag**, but importing image files will raise this error.

#### TS2307: Cannot find module './Octocat.jpg'.

https://github.com/github0013/typescript_react/commit/6670f3ca74404007ad1ed6e4ab0d111f547ee75d

I am still new to typescript, webpack and react, and I am sure I am confused typescript's `import` and webpack's.

How do I enable `url-loader` for images? and is this even valid?
https://github.com/github0013/typescript_react/blob/master/config/webpack/environment.js

--
I did try `require` but it will just return image's path instead of base64 stirng.

```js
// global.d.ts
declare function require(string): string;
```

Answer (score 1):

solved..

webpacker 3.0.2 already had loaders for image files
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/tree/v3.0.2/package/loaders
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/v3.0.2/package/loaders/file.js

`environment.loaders`, in rails' `config/webpack/environment.js`, is just a map, and `jpeg png gif` are in `file` loader. 
https://github.com/github0013/typescript_react/commit/dc97c3aa9f17bc4f3b0210a426aac27092c5ae7f#diff-41713e6b116dc5cc2bbea556a85db322R3

so overriding file loader's test, then add own image loader will use `url-loader` for `jpeg png gif`
https://github.com/github0013/typescript_react/commit/dc97c3aa9f17bc4f3b0210a426aac27092c5ae7f

after adding the loader, regular image `require` in typescript will return base64 string.